# If $A,B$ have the same trace, then $A=T^{-1}BT$, for some invertible matrix $T.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A, B$ be $n\times n$ invertible matrices. If $A,B$ have the same trace, could someone advise me how to show $A=T^{-1}BT$, for some invertible matrix $T$ ? Is it possible to do so using knowledge only from a first course in linear algebra?

Comment: no, it is false

Answer (score 3):

The statement is not true.

Let $$A=\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\2&2\end{bmatrix}$$

$$B=\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\5&1\end{bmatrix}$$

Note that $A$ is singular and $B$ is invertible so they are not similar.

Comment: Noted. Is the statement be true if $A$  and $B$ are both invertible?

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo Not even then. Observe that the determinants of $B$ and $T^{-1}BT$ are equal.

Answer (score 3):

Eigenvalues are invariant under conjugation: $B$ and $T^{-1}BT$ have the same eigenvalues. The trace is the sum of the eigenvalues.

So what you're asking would imply that if the sum of the eigenvalues of $A$ and $B$ are the same, then the set of eigenvalues are identical. But this clearly can't hold because $1 + 1 = 0 + 2$.

Also, while $A = T^{-1}BT$ implies that $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues, it is not true that if $A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues then $A = T^{-1}BT$ for some $T$. For example:

$$ A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, B = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}. $$

$A$ and $B$ have the same eigenvalues: $1$ (with algebraic multiplicity $2$) but you can see that $T^{-1}BT = T^{-1}T = I \ne A$.

What is correct is that if $A$ and $B$ have the same [Jordan decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan_normal_form) then $A = T^{-1}BT$ for some invertible matrix $T$ (we say $A$ and $B$ are *similar* if this happens). An easy example of this is when $A$ and $B$ are diagonalizable with the same eigenvalues (counted with multiplicity).

Answer (score 2):

The statement is false.

Let $A$ be any nonzero matrix with trace zero and let $B = 0$. Then $A$ and $B$ have the same trace but
$$T^{-1}BT = 0 \ne A$$
for all invertible matrices $T$.

Comment: Noted. Is the statement be true if $A$  and $B$ are both invertible?

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo No, consider $\begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 \end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 0 \\ 0 & -2 \end{bmatrix}$. They have different determinants and hence cannot be similar.

Comment: Thank you. What are the additional condtions required for the statement to be true? I am actually reading up on this: Let $G$ be a group. Two representations $A,B: G \to GL(n, \mathbb{C})$ are equivalent iff tr$(A(g))=$ tr$(B(g))$ for all $g\in G$. I can't seem to find any proof of this statement that only involves elementary linear algebra.

Comment: @AlexyVincenzo See my answer. I believe (but my memory on this isn't 100%) that for representations, the algebraic and geometric multiplicities are all $1$ (i.e. the matrices are diagonalizable) and therefore the condition I give in the last paragraph applies. But that only applies to a single matrix $A(g)$ and not the whole set of matrices determined by $A$—meaning that $T$ might (in principle) depend on $g$.

Comment: They are not all one in general unless the group is abelian.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two matrices $A,B,$ with the same characteristic polynomials and minimal polynomials. But not similar.

$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
7&0&0&0 \\
0&7&0&0 \\
0&0&7&1 \\
0&0&0&7 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

$$
A =
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
7&1&0&0 \\
0&7&0&0 \\
0&0&7&1 \\
0&0&0&7 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$